# Java Graphics2D drawImage() and clip(): how to apply antialiasing?

Tags: java

The `BufferedImage` drawn by the `drawImage` and `clip` method of Java Graphics2D have jagged edges, how to apply antialiasing?

[image]

The code:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\Pictures\\U\\U\\3306231465660486.jpg"));

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(new JPanel() {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.drawLine(10, 10, 300, 100);


        g2d.translate(50, 200);
        g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(30), getWidth() / 2.0, getHeight() / 2.0);
        g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
        g2d.clip(new Rectangle(-110, 110, 80, 110));
        g2d.fill(new Rectangle(-100, 100, 100, 100));
    }
});

frame.setSize(600, 600);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: OK, the `clip` part is an entirely different story. It's probably not so simple to solve. (One approach would be to do the clipping manually, using an `Area`, but whether or not this is feasible depends on how the `clip` was supposed to be used *exactly*). I have sketched one approach, but think that it might be better to basically undo the edit here (so that *this* question is **only** about the `drawImage` case), and ask a *new* question, specifically about the `clip` method.

Answer (score 5):

For the image, it is sufficient to paint the image into another image that is 2 pixels larger, and then draw the resulting image with bilinear interpolation. So you can just pass your image through a method like this one:

```
private static BufferedImage addBorder(BufferedImage image)
{
    BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(
        image.getWidth() + 2, image.getHeight() + 2, 
        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = result.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, 1, 1, null);
    g.dispose();
    return result;
}
```

The result will be this:

[image: RotatedImageBorder]

Here is the MCVE, including the line that sets the `..._INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR` rendering hint:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ImageBorderAntialiasing
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui()
    {
        //BufferedImage img = loadUnchecked("7bI1Y.jpg");
        BufferedImage img = addBorder(loadUnchecked("7bI1Y.jpg"));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new JPanel()
        {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2d.setRenderingHint(
                    RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

                g2d.setRenderingHint(
                    RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);

                g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                g2d.drawLine(10, 10, 300, 100);

                g2d.translate(50, 200);
                g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(30), 
                    getWidth() / 2.0, getHeight() / 2.0);
                g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
                g2d.fill(new Rectangle(-100, 100, 100, 100));
            }
        });

        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static BufferedImage addBorder(BufferedImage image)
    {
        BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(
            image.getWidth() + 2, image.getHeight() + 2, 
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = result.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image, 1, 1, null);
        g.dispose();
        return result;
    }

    private static BufferedImage loadUnchecked(String fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            return ImageIO.read(new File(fileName));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

---

<sup>After this was answered, the question was updated to also ask about the `clip` method</sup>

---

Antialiasing the result of a `clip` operation may be more difficult. The `clip` operation is very hard "by nature" (and I assume that it eventually will be handled by something like a [Stencil Buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stencil_buffer) in hardware).

One approach to solve this *could* be do do the clipping manually. So instead of doing

```
g2d.clip(new Rectangle(-110, 110, 80, 110));
g2d.fill(new Rectangle(-100, 100, 100, 100));
```

you could do something like

```
Shape clip = new Rectangle(-110, 110, 80, 110);
Shape rectangleA = new Rectangle(-100, 100, 100, 100);  
g2d.fill(clip(clip, rectangleA));
```

where the `clip` method is implemented to to manually compute the intersection of the shapes.

**Note:** Computing the intersection of two shapes *can* be rather expensive. If this becomes an issue, one might have to revise the approach. But on another note: I've heavily been doing Swing programming for ~20 years now, and cannot remember to *ever* have used the `Graphics2D#clip` method *at all*....

The difference between using `Graphics2D#clip` and the manual clipping is shown here:

[image: Clipper]

and a closeup:

[image: ClipperZoom]

And there is the code:

(It does no longer contain the image part, because the problems are fairly unrelated...)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.Area;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ClippedDrawingAntialiasing
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JPanel()
        {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2d.setRenderingHint(
                    RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

                g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                g2d.drawLine(10, 10, 300, 100);

                g2d.translate(50, 200);
                g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(30), 
                    getWidth() / 2.0, getHeight() / 2.0);

                g2d.clip(new Rectangle(-110, 110, 80, 110));

                g2d.fill(new Rectangle(-100, 100, 100, 100));            

                g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g2d.fill(new Rectangle(-60, 120, 60, 170));            
            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JPanel()
        {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2d.setRenderingHint(
                    RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

                g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                g2d.drawLine(10, 10, 300, 100);

                g2d.translate(50, 200);
                g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(30), 
                    getWidth() / 2.0, getHeight() / 2.0);

                Clipper clipper = 
                    new Clipper(new Rectangle(-110, 110, 80, 110));

                g2d.fill(clipper.clip(new Rectangle(-100, 100, 100, 100)));            

                g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g2d.fill(clipper.clip(new Rectangle(-60, 120, 60, 170)));            
            }
        });

        frame.setSize(1200, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class Clipper 
    {
        private final Shape shape;
        Clipper(Shape shape)
        {
            this.shape = shape;
        }

        Shape clip(Shape other)
        {
            Area a = new Area(shape);
            a.intersect(new Area(other));
            return a;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although this is a workaround, it is still ineffective for the `clip` method, and may cause additional memory overhead in actual applications. So I need to find a better solution.

Comment: @Yii.Guxing If there are additional requirements, then you should state them in the question. Edit the question to explain how the `clip` method is relevant here.

Comment: Thanks for your supplementary reply, your solution has given me a lot of inspiration, we can use the `TexturePaint` class and the `fill()` method to solve this problem. But it brings a new problem: the rendered image is a bit fuzzy. Do you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52846928/java-graphics2d-rendering-images-using-texturepaint-is-blurry

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to blur the border of the image once you load it. You should also use the `RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING` with `RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY`.

This is the final result:

[image]

The full code is available below. Note that is uses a blur method described by [Marco13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3182664/marco13) in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22744303/4289700.

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.MultipleGradientPaint;
import java.awt.RadialGradientPaint;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    private static BufferedImage blurImageBorder(BufferedImage input, double border) {
        int w = input.getWidth();
        int h = input.getHeight();
        BufferedImage output = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics2D g = output.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(input, 0, 0, null);

        g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.DstOut);
        Color c0 = new Color(0x000000FF);

        // Left
        g.setPaint(new GradientPaint(new Point2D.Double(0, border), c0, new Point2D.Double(border, border), c0));
        g.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, border, border, h- border - border));

        // Right
        g.setPaint(new GradientPaint(new Point2D.Double(w - border, border), c0, new Point2D.Double(w, border), c0));
        g.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(w- border, border, border, h- border - border));

        // Top
        g.setPaint(new GradientPaint(new Point2D.Double(border, 0), c0, new Point2D.Double(border, border), c0));
        g.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(border, 0, w - border - border, border));

        // Bottom
        g.setPaint(new GradientPaint(new Point2D.Double(border, h - border), c0, new Point2D.Double(border, h), c0));
        g.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(border, h - border, w - border - border, border));

        final float[] floatArray = new float[]{ 0, 1 };
        final Color[] colorArray = new Color[]{ c0, c0 };

        // Top Left
        g.setPaint(new RadialGradientPaint(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, border + border, border + border),
                floatArray, colorArray, MultipleGradientPaint.CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE));
        g.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, border, border));

        // Top Right
        g.setPaint(new RadialGradientPaint(
                new Rectangle2D.Double(w - border - border, 0, border + border, border + border),
                floatArray, colorArray, MultipleGradientPaint.CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE));
        g.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(w - border, 0, border, border));

        // Bottom Left
        g.setPaint(new RadialGradientPaint(
                new Rectangle2D.Double(0, h - border - border, border + border, border + border),
                floatArray, colorArray, MultipleGradientPaint.CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE));
        g.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, h - border, border, border));

        // Bottom Right
        g.setPaint(new RadialGradientPaint(
                new Rectangle2D.Double(w - border - border, h - border - border, border + border, border + border),
                floatArray, colorArray, MultipleGradientPaint.CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE));
        g.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(w - border, h - border, border, border));

        g.dispose();

        return output;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage raw = ImageIO.read(new File("/path/to/picture.jpg"));
        BufferedImage img = blurImageBorder(raw, 1);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new JPanel() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

                g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                g2d.drawLine(10, 10, 300, 100);

                g2d.translate(50, 200);
                g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(30), getWidth() / 2.0, getHeight() / 2.0);

                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

                g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
                g2d.fill(new Rectangle(-100, 100, 100, 100));
            }
        });

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although this is a workaround, it is still ineffective for the `clip` method, and may cause additional memory overhead in actual applications. So I need to find a better solution.